# Error: invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="5.01", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.7.0)

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethers.js, binance-smart-chain

I get this error, I tried to convert value values ​​to String as proposed in some solutions but nothing

[image]

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require('http');
const Web3=  require("web3")
const ethers = require("ethers");
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3888;
var wss = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
const web3 = new Web3(wss)

const secretKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
const PAN_ROUTER_ADDRESS =  "0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E";
const BNB_CONTRACT = "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c"
const swapAbi =  [{"inputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"_name","type":"string"},{"internalType":"string","name":"_symbol","type":"string"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_decimals","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_supply","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_txFee","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_burnFee","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_charityFee","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_FeeAddress","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenOwner","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"inputs":[],"name":"FeeAddress","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"_BURN_FEE","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"_CHARITY_FEE","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"_TAX_FEE","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"_owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"burn","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"subtractedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"decreaseAllowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tAmount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"deliver","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"excludeAccount","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"includeAccount","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"addedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"increaseAllowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"isCharity","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"isExcluded","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mint","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tAmount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"deductTransferFee","type":"bool"}],"name":"reflectionFromToken","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"setAsCharityAccount","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"rAmount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"tokenFromReflection","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"totalBurn","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"totalCharity","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"totalFees","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_txFee","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_burnFee","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_charityFee","type":"uint256"}],"name":"updateFee","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]
const abi = [{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_factory","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_WETH","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"inputs":[],"name":"WETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountADesired","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBDesired","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountAMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"addLiquidity","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenDesired","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"addLiquidityETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountToken","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"factory","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveOut","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getAmountIn","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveOut","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getAmountOut","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"}],"name":"getAmountsIn","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"}],"name":"getAmountsOut","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"reserveB","type":"uint256"}],"name":"quote","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountAMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidity","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountToken","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approveMax","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETHWithPermit","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountToken","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountTokenMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETHMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approveMax","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"removeLiquidityETHWithPermitSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountETH","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"liquidity","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountAMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountBMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approveMax","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"removeLiquidityWithPermit","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountA","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountB","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapETHForExactTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactETHForTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountIn","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountInMax","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapTokensForExactETH","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOut","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountInMax","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapTokensForExactTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"receive"}]
function calculate_gas_price(action, amount){
  if (action==="buy"){
    return ethers.utils.formatUnits(amount.add(100), 'gwei')
  }else{
    return ethers.utils.formatUnits(amount.sub(100), 'gwei')
  }
}
function router(account) {
  return new ethers.Contract(
    PAN_ROUTER_ADDRESS,
      [
          'function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] memory path) public view returns (uint[] memory amounts)',
          'function swapExactTokensForTokens(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external returns (uint[] memory amounts)',
          'function swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external returns (uint[] memory amounts)',
          'function swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external payable',
          'function swapExactTokensForETH (uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external payable'
      ],
      account
  );
}
function erc20(account,tokenAddress) {
  return new ethers.Contract(
      tokenAddress,
      [{
          "constant": true,
          "inputs": [{"name": "_owner", "type": "address"}],
          "name": "balanceOf",
          "outputs": [{"name": "balance", "type": "uint256"}],
          "payable": false,
          "type": "function"
      },
      {"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},
      {"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},
      {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [{"name": "_spender","type": "address"},{"name": "_value","type": "uint256"}],
        "name": "approve",
        "outputs": [{"name": "","type": "bool"}],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
      },
    ],
      account
  );
}
const buyToken = async(account,tokenContract,gasLimit,gasPrice)=>{
  //buyAmount how much are we going to pay for example 0.1 BNB
  const buyAmount = 0.5

  //Slippage refers to the difference between the expected price of a trade and the price at which the trade is executed
  const slippage = 10

  //amountOutMin how many token we are going to receive
  let amountOutMin = 0;
  const amountIn = ethers.utils.parseUnits(buyAmount.toString(), 'ether');
  if (parseInt(slippage) !== 0) {
    const amounts = await router(account).getAmountsOut(amountIn, [BNB_CONTRACT, tokenContract]);
    amountOutMin = amounts[1].sub(amounts[1].div(100).mul(`${slippage}`));
  }
  const tx = await router(account).swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
    amountOutMin,
    [BNB_CONTRACT, tokenContract],
    account.address,
    (Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 10),
    {
        'value': amountIn,
        'gasLimit': gasLimit,
        'gasPrice': gasPrice,
    }
  );
  const receipt = await tx.wait();
  if (receipt && receipt.blockNumber && receipt.status === 1) { // 0 - failed, 1 - success
    console.log(`Transaction https://bscscan.com/tx/${receipt.transactionHash} mined, status success`);
  } else if (receipt && receipt.blockNumber && receipt.status === 0) {
    console.log(`Transaction https://bscscan.com/tx/${receipt.transactionHash} mined, status failed`);
  } else {
    console.log(`Transaction https://bscscan.com/tx/${receipt.transactionHash} not mined`);
  }
}
const sellToken = async(account,tokenContract,gasLimit,gasPrice,value=99)=>{
  const sellTokenContract = new ethers.Contract(tokenContract,swapAbi,account)
  const contract = new ethers.Contract(PAN_ROUTER_ADDRESS,abi,account)
  const accountAddress = account.address
  const tokenBalance = await erc20(account,tokenContract).balanceOf(accountAddress);
  let amountOutMin = 0;
  const amountIn = tokenBalance.mul(value).div(100)
  const amounts = await router(account).getAmountsOut(amountIn, [tokenContract,BNB_CONTRACT]);
  if (parseInt(slippage) !== 0) {
    amountOutMin = amounts[1].sub(amounts[1].mul(`${slippage}`).div(100));
  } else {
    amountOutMin = amounts[1]
  }
  const approve = await sellTokenContract.approve(PAN_ROUTER_ADDRESS, amountIn)
  const receipt_approve = await approve.wait();
  if (receipt_approve && receipt_approve.blockNumber && receipt_approve.status === 1) { 
    console.log(`Approved https://bscscan.com/tx/${receipt_approve.transactionHash}`);
    const swap_txn = await contract.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
      amountIn ,amountOutMin, 
      [tokenContract, BNB_CONTRACT],
      accountAddress,
      (Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 10),
      {
        'gasLimit': gasLimit,
        'gasPrice': gasPrice,
      }
    )
    const receipt = await swap_txn.wait();
    if (receipt && receipt.blockNumber && receipt.status === 1) { // 0 - failed, 1 - success
      console.log(`Transaction https://bscscan.com/tx/${receipt.transactionHash} mined, status success`);
    } else if (receipt && receipt.blockNumber && receipt.status === 0) {
      console.log(`Transaction https://bscscan.com/tx/${receipt.transactionHash} mined, status failed`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Transaction https://bscscan.com/tx/${receipt.transactionHash} not mined`);
    }
  }
}
var init = async function () {
  var customWsProvider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(wss);
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(secretKey);
  const account = wallet.connect(customWsProvider)
  const iface = new ethers.utils.Interface(['function    swapExactETHForTokens(uint256 amountOutMin, address[] path, address to, uint256 deadline)',
'function swapETHForExactTokens(uint amountOut, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)',
'function swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(uint amountOutMin,address[] calldata path,address to,uint deadline)'])

customWsProvider.on("pending", (tx) => {
  customWsProvider.getTransaction(tx).then(async function (transaction) {
  // now we will only listen for pending transaction on pancakesswap factory
  if(transaction && transaction.to==="0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E"){
    const value = web3.utils.fromWei(transaction.value.toString())
    const gasPrice= web3.utils.fromWei(transaction.gasPrice.toString())
    const gasLimit= web3.utils.fromWei(transaction.gasLimit.toString())
  // for example we will be only showing transaction that are higher than 30 bnb
    if(value>3) {
      console.log("value : ",value);
      console.log("gasPrice : ",gasPrice);
      console.log("gasLimit : ",gasLimit);
      //we can print the sender of that transaction
      console.log("from",transaction.from);
      let result = []
      //we will use try and catch to handle the error and decode the data of the function used to swap the token
      try {
        result = iface.decodeFunctionData('swapExactETHForTokens', transaction.data)
      } catch (error) {
      try {
        result = iface.decodeFunctionData('swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens', transaction.data)
      } catch (error) {
      try {
        result = iface.decodeFunctionData('swapETHForExactTokens', transaction.data)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("final err : ",transaction);
      }
      }
      }
      if(result.length>0){
        let tokenAddress = ""
        if(result[1].length>0){
          tokenAddress = result[1][1]
          console.log("tokenAddress",tokenAddress);
          const buyGasPrice = calculate_gas_price("buy",transaction.gasPrice)
          const sellGasPrice = calculate_gas_price("sell",transaction.gasPrice)
          // after calculating the gas price we buy the token
          console.log("going to buy");
          await buyToken(account,tokenAddress,transaction.gasLimit,buyGasPrice)
          // after buying the token we sell it 
          console.log("going to sell the token");
          await sellToken(account,tokenAddress,transaction.gasLimit,sellGasPrice)
        }
      }
    }
    }
  });
});

customWsProvider._websocket.on("error", async (ep) => {

console.log(`Unable to connect to ${ep.subdomain} retrying in 3s...`);
setTimeout(init, 3000);
});
customWsProvider._websocket.on("close", async (code) => {
console.log(
`Connection lost with code ${code}! Attempting reconnect in 3s...`
);
customWsProvider._websocket.terminate();
setTimeout(init, 3000);
});
};

init();
//now we create the express server
const server = http.createServer(app);
// we launch the server
server.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`)});
```

Comment: From the error message it seems you are using "5.01" as a BigNumber and it doesn't support using decimals digits.

Comment: How I can solve this?

Comment: In some place of the code it is sending "5.01" where a BigNumber is expected. I'd check what value it is expecting, it could be the wrong unit is used, or perhaps it is some rounding error.